# How can I use kerberos under python elasticsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kerberos, pyelasticsearch

I checked the documentation of [elasticsearch:7.x](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.x/api.html) but still didn't find the way how I can force the python `ES` package to use my kerberos token.

I can reach the `ES` through a browser, `curl` *( `curl --negotiate -u` )* and `requests` with `requests_kerberos` *( with mutual `OPTIONAL` config )* but with the python elasticsearch package calling a simple `es.cat.health()` I get `401` `AuthenticationException`...

My questions are:

- where was I wrong, what did I miss?
- is it even possible to force the ES python lib to use kerberos or does it work under the hood?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a robot or something that decreases the scores? What's the problem with my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems We've found a solution, but basically not from the docs.

I've read in the doc about the `Elasticsearch` object can receive `http_auth` input, but unfortunately I didn't find what it exactly waits for.

So, you can force the `Elasticsearch` to use the `HTTPKerberosAuth` class from the `requests_kerberos` lib in same way as you can use that for a simple get request >

```
es = Elasticsearch(<host>, http_auth=HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=OPTIONAL))
```

It works well, but any other suggestions, knowledge share or comments are welcomed.